# Активировать определенный адрес страницы из PHP кода

Tags: php, telegram-bot, cron, webhook

Извините заранее, если задам глупый вопрос или буду называть вещи неправильно. Я только учусь :)
Суть вот в чем:
Начинаю изучать PHP и в качестве первых шагов решил попрактиковаться в написании бота для Telegram.
Зарегистрировал бота, активировал работу через Webhook (В командную строку браузера вводится ссылка по шаблону https://api.telegram.org/bot******/setWebhook?url=https://******/api_telegramm/*****.php и активируется) и вроде все хорошо, но. С какой-то периодичностью связь с телеграммом теряется, webhook в строке состояния выводит совсем другой сайт (это даже на сайт не похоже, а больше на шифр какой-то) и помогает только переактивация webhook. Естественно вручную делать такое не хочется и решил заморочиться, чтоб переактивация происходила автоматически. Немного работав с /cron-job.org/, решил создать страницу на которой при помощи

```
header("Location: https://api.telegram.org/bot...");
exit();
```

перенаправлять на требуемый мне адрес. Но меня ждало разочарование. Оказывается в cron-job переадресация не обрабатывается и кроны дают сбой (Если же я переходил по странице через браузер, то меня перекидывало и все срабатывало).
Также пробовал через

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
           window.location = "https://api.telegram.org/bot..."
      </script>';
```

Такой крон срабатывал, но активация не происходила (Если я переходил вручную, через браузер, то все активировалось).
Пытался найти еще какие-нибудь функции для активации, но ничего подходящего не нахожу :( Подскажите, пожалуйста, как из PHP страницы можно активировать определенный адрес страницы, и чтоб этот запрос обработался КРОНом.
Спасибо большое

Comment: Если отверить прямо на ваш вопрос, то вы хотите `file_get_contents('https://example.com/some/path?some=params')`, но мне что-то подсказывает что присутсвует [Ошибка XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-xy/710#710) и следует разобраться с тем почему ломается webhook, т.к. например у меня за несколько лет ни разу не было такого что бы webhook на боте произвольно ломался

Comment: @Ein Спасибо Вам огромное. Все сработало :) Проходя всевозможные уроки данной функцией читал содержимое файла и даже подумать не мог, что ею можно переадресовывать. А по поводу Ошибки XY - Вы правы. Но по вопросу ломания Вэбхуков было много тем и окончательного решения не найдено. Вот и побоялся, что и моя не увенчается успехом. Большинство пишут, что код не верный (но я брал даже официальный со страницы телеграмма). Думаю, что все это из-за того, что я работаю с бесплатным хостингом 000Вэбхост.